# Find matches between elements in an array? (C)

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to code a program that will take input and insert into an array called `numbers`. From there using nested while loops scan for duplicates in  `numbers`. 
The amount of matches for each element should be inserted into the `matches` array.

It works for the first element, however I get rubbish data for the rest of the elements.

```
int main(void){
  int numbers[6]; //Array to hold input numbers
  int counter = 0;
  int size = 0;
  int matches[6];
  int counterOne = 0;
  int counterTwo = 0;

  while (counter<6) { //scan all numbers input from user
    scanf("%d", &numbers[counter]);
    size++;
    counter++;
  }

  while (counterOne < 6) {
    counterTwo = 0;
    while (counterTwo < 6) {
      if (numbers[counterOne] == numbers[counterTwo]) {
        matches[counterOne]++;
      }
      counterTwo++;
    }
    counterOne++;
  }

  for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
  {
    printf("%d\n", matches[i] );
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add sample input, desired output, actual output and an explanation of what exactly makes it "rubbish".

Comment: As basic precaution, please explain how and where you init your arrays and check the return values of called functions like `scanf()`.

Comment: Afterwards try https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and if that does not help https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/

Comment: `numbers[0] == numbers[0]` so you have a false match there...

Comment: Hello close voter, please explain in which this differs from the description of a MCVE. It is probably hard for a newbie to understand what needs to be changed.

Comment: @John3136 That is true but only makes an off-by-one error for the results. I somehow doubt that it is what OP describes as "rubbish".

Comment: @Yunnosch That's why it is a comment ;-). But in reality we don't have inputs, outputs and expected outputs so who knows if off by 1 is rubbish or not. Probably why it was close voted (not by me)

Comment: The matches array is uninitialized

Comment: Even though you got answers, please improve your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialize your `matches` array with 0. Reading an uninitialised variable (`++` is read and write) is undefined behavior. Most of the time you just get what is in the memory before you allocated your variable, but this is not required by the standard.

To fix this change `int matches[6];` to `int matches[6] = {0};`

This sets all entries in the array to 0.

Be careful though, this is does not mean that `int matches[6] = {1};` would set everything to `1`. This is a partial array initialisation. Basically you just set the first value to what is in brackets and the rest gets filled up with `0`.

`int matches[6] = {1,2};` would be the same as `{1,2,0,0,0,0}`

Answer (score 1):

The matches array is not initialized which is why you get garbage value when you increment. Use int matches[6] = {0}; instead.